# copying array to another object property javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I have two objects:

`Group` which has a `users` property, containing an array of ObjectIds:

```
["59f5c8b62f73d036bc4f5673","59f5c7d42f73d036bc4f566b",
"59f5c81a2f73d036bc4f566d","59f5c8482f73d036bc4f566f"]
```

And another object which has a property which needs to be populated with that exact array of objectIds, so when I create it in the back, it looks like this right now:

```
var object = new Object({
      title: req.body.title
      group: req.params.id,
      objectArray: { user: group.users, value: 1 }
    });
```

I am expecting to get the population as follows:

```
object: {
    title: some-title,
    group: someRefId,
    objectArray: [ 
       {user: ObjectId1, value: 1},
       {user: ObjectId2, value: 1},
       {user: ObjectId3, value: 1},
       {user: ObjectId4, value: 1}
    ]
}
```

I need to iterate through that array somehow and then declare `{user: user of group.users, value:1}` or something. I don't understand how to iterate through that array while declaring a new object...

Comment: You may want to look at `Array.prototype.map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var req = {
  body: {
    title: 'some-title'
  },
  params: {
    id: 'someRefId'
  }
};

var group = {
  users: [
    "59f5c8b62f73d036bc4f5673",
    "59f5c7d42f73d036bc4f566b",
    "59f5c81a2f73d036bc4f566d",
    "59f5c8482f73d036bc4f566f"
  ]
};

var object = {
  title: req.body.title,
  group: req.params.id,
  objectArray: group.users.map(function(user) {
    return {
      user: user,
      value: 1
    };
  })
};

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.map` to do this.

**ES6**

```
...
objectArray: group.users.map((user) => ({ user, value: 1 }))
...
```

**ES5**

```
...
objectArray: group.users.map(function (user) {
    return { 
        user: user, 
        value: 1 
    };
})
...
```